# Alinear columnas HTML con ngFor angular

Tags: html, angular

Tengo el siguiente codigo en angular para alinear ciertos datos pero me da un resultado asi, con espacios entre columnas y nose como quitarlos
[image: Actual]

Codigo

```
     <div class="row">
          <div *ngFor="let costconfig of model.costDetails; let j = index" [attr.data-index]="j">
            <div class="row">     
              <div class="text-right margin-left-3" *ngIf="!costconfig.costEffect">
                <div class="row col-sm-12">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div *ngIf="costconfig.code=='Labor'">
                      {{costconfig.code}}(-):   {{ costconfig.costAmount }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row col-sm-12">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div *ngIf="costconfig.code=='Part'">
                      {{costconfig.code}}(-):  {{ costconfig.costAmount }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                    <div *ngIf="costconfig.code=='IGST'">
                      {{costconfig.code}}(-):  {{ costconfig.costAmount }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                    <div *ngIf="costconfig.code=='CGST'">
                      {{costconfig.code}}(-):  {{ costconfig.costAmount }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row col-sm-12">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div *ngIf="costconfig.code=='SGST'">
                      {{costconfig.code}}(-):  {{ costconfig.costAmount }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Este es el array que estoy pasando:

```
 model.costDetails: [
{
  code: "Labor";
  costAmount: 150;
},
{
  code: "Part";
  costAmount: 2141;
},
{
  code: "Spl Disc";
  costAmount: 0;
},
{
  code: "IGST";
  costAmount: 572.75;
},
{
  code: "CGST";
  costAmount: 0;
},
{
  code: "SGST";
  costAmount: 0;
}
```

];

Resultado esperado:
[image: Resultado esperado]

Comment: Será algo del contenido que estás generando... Si lo pongo a pelo me sale "bien". [Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/qcdsnxw2/)

Comment: En los col del primer y ultimo row pon `col-sm-12`.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev no funcionó amigo

Comment: Un div con la clase `row` es una fila, no una columna y no debe llevar clases de columna también en su lista de clases. No se porque lo has cambiado, ahora esta peor que antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de las filas, o mejor dicho, los `row`, siempre se define el tamaño de las rejillas que le pondrás a cada contenido. El error está que estás definiendo a `col-sm-12` en la misma posición del `row`, de la cual no lo reconocerá, ya que el ancho del `row` dependerá al tamaño de las rejillas que le definas **adentro**. Tendrías que quitarlo y dejar todo como está, tu código quedaría así:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div *ngFor="let costconfig of quotationDetailsMasterModel.costDetails; let j = index" [attr.data-index]="j">
  <div class="text-right margin-left-3" *ngIf="!costconfig.costEffect">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div *ngIf="costconfig.code=='Labor'">
          {{costconfig.code}}(-):   {{ costconfig.costAmount }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div *ngIf="costconfig.code=='Part'">
          {{costconfig.code}}(-):  {{ costconfig.costAmount }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div *ngIf="costconfig.code=='IGST'">
          {{costconfig.code}}(-):  {{ costconfig.costAmount }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div *ngIf="costconfig.code=='CGST'">
          {{costconfig.code}}(-):  {{ costconfig.costAmount }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div *ngIf="costconfig.code=='SGST'">
          {{costconfig.code}}(-):  {{ costconfig.costAmount }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en el siguiente [proyecto](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/dyKzKRL).

Comment: lo intente pero no funciona

Comment: Bueno los resultados son tal cual a lo que muestras en la imagen